# Thinkpad edge e535 Ubuntu 12.04 issues

Tags: drivers, lenovo, webcam, fingerprint-reader

I have a lenovo thinkpad edge e535 AMD A8 laptop. I purchased it a couple of years ago with Windows 7 preinstalled. Before a couple of months, I decided to install Ubuntu on this laptop for several reasons. So, I picked the latest 64-bit version and I installed it. After installation, it wasn't feasible to use the camera or fingertip etc. However, the general performance and experience was far better than Windows 7 on this laptop. Having searched a lot I realized that for the better operation of my laptop, I had to format my laptop and install an older version of Ubuntu, 12.04. I did so and the result is the same.

I would be grateful to everyone who could provide me with a solution.

Thank you very much in advance.

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 5986:02d2 Acer, Inc 
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21f4 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 147e:1002 Upek 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Wireless Mouse M305
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Comment: Could you add output of `lsusb`

Comment: sure thing, please see my updated post.